Strapi v5 populating relations
In Strapi v5 I've got these linked collection types, all many-to-many: patients, allergies, comorbidities, prescriptions. This all works perfectly well in the admin area. I view a patient: there are his allergies, his comorbidities, his prescriptions. I view an allergy: there is the list of patients suffering from it. And so forth. All is well.
However, when I run an API request through the browser and ask it please to populate the relationships -- e.g., http://localhost:1337/api/patients?populate=* -- I get unpopulated arrays of the relationships. For (simplified) example:
{"full_name":"Fakey McFakeFace","allergies":[],"prescriptions":[],"comorbidities":[]}
Fakey McFakeFace definitely has allergies, prescriptions, and comorbidities, and they all show up in detail in the admin interface.
It appears to me in the Strapi documentation that populate=* is supposed to result in these things appearing. But they do not.
Yes, all these collection types are published and set to be findOne- and findMany-able by a public user.
So I guess my question is:
What am I missing? Ideas greatly appreciated.

Have you tried strapi v5 plugin populate?
Its fork of the original strapi plugin populate which does not support Strapi v5 at the time.
populate=* only populates one relation, 1 level deep, but with the plugin above you can populate with custom depth or default max depth. Your Api call would look like :
/api/articles?pLevel

or
/api/articles?pLevel=10


Thanks very much for responding -- I did try that plugin actually, so, excellent suggestion! Unfortunately the result was the same. The response comes back with an indication that related arrays do exist, but it doesn't populate them with any elements. Evidently it's not an issue of how many levels deep, but something else.
